# Refactoring my code for asynchronous NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uiactivityindicatorview, delegation

There are problems with using synchronous requests. The problem is that I am not really sure how to refactor the code below to use an asynchronous request to accomplish the following two tasks:

1. Use a `UIActivityIndicatorView` subview to notify of active fetching;
2. Implement a `Reachability` check before the connection request to ensure that there is an Internet connection and that the host is available, i.e. `reachabilityWithHostName:@"wwww.mywebhostingisterrible.com"`.

Currently I have a `Fetcher` class with a `+(Fetcher *)sharedFetcher` singleton that is used in all of my view controllers to fetch data. Currently all data is fetched using the following code:

```
- (NSString *)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

A method that fetches looks like this:

```
-(NSArray *)fetchDogFoodListing {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@query/dogFood/%@/%lli/%@/%@",self.connectionUrl,self.queryCriteria.dogFoodName,self.queryCriteria.dogFoodBrandId,self.queryCriteria.dogFoodIngredients,self.queryCriteria.dogFoodBrand];
    NSString *json = [self stringWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    return [self.factory buildIKDogFoodArrayWithJSON:json];
}
```

and a call from the `UIViewController` in `-(void)viewDidLoad` looks like this:

```
self.dogFoods = [[IKFetcher sharedFetcher] fetchDogFoodListing];
```

I have thought about implementing a delegate in this situation but I am very shaky on how delegation ought to work. I'm not even sure which way it should go. Should the `Fetcher` have a `FetcherDelegate` that can notify the view controller of when it is done, so the UI can update? Should the view controller have a delegate so that the fetcher can update the view when stuff is done?

I'm sure based on my questions you can see my inexperience with delegation, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         //.. do stuff with data here...
    }
}
```

or you could just do the sendSynchronousRequest code inside a dispatch_sync if you want the connection to be synchronous, though you should really should be as asynchronous as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that I realized that was a possibility, but I would like to avoid it and use the async callbacks available to NSURLConnection

Comment: If we are an the same page you can easily do things like that. I have a class encapsulates NSURLConnection and uses its delegate methods https://github.com/Machx/Zangetsu/blob/master/Source/CWURLRequest.m you could use this code or do something similar.

Comment: Nice stuff... so my question would be, how would I re-factor my existing code to use some of the implementation you have provided? For example, right now it is convenient for me to use the one-liner `self.dogFoods = [[IKFetcher sharedFetcher] fetchDogFoodListing];` because the instance method `-(NSArray *)fetchDogFoodListing` returns an `NSArray` that I am interested in. What do you suggest that I do to return stuff in that fashion? Wait for a response from async then return the data?

Comment: If you have a class like that personally I would have a method like [[IKFetcher sharedFetcher] fetchDogFoodListingWithCompletionBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) { if(data){ [self setDogFoods:data]; } else { //log error } }]; this way you can fetch the data and when its ready then you can call any additional methods needed in the completion block.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to look at the brilliant framework by Mugunth Kumar:

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit

I plan on using this for NSURLConnection in my future projects